# automatically generating a link anchor according to the initials

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of terms (along with their descriptions) in the following format.

```
<dt style="font-weight:bold">A1</dt>
<dd>Some description for A1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">A2</dt>
<dd>Some description for A2</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">B1</dt>
<dd>Some description for B1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">C1</dt>
<dd>Some description for C1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">C2</dt>
<dd>Some description for C2</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">D1</dt>
<dd>Some description for D1</dd>
```

I need to be able to insert anchor links like this:

```
<a href="#A"></a>
<dt style="font-weight:bold">A1</dt>
<dd>Some description for A1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">A2</dt>
<dd>Some description for A2</dd>

<a href="#B"></a>
<dt style="font-weight:bold">B1</dt>
<dd>Some description for B1</dd>

<a href="#C"></a>
<dt style="font-weight:bold">C1</dt>
<dd>Some description for C1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">C2</dt>
<dd>Some description for C2</dd>

<a href="#D"></a>
<dt style="font-weight:bold">D1</dt>
<dd>Some description for D1</dd>
```

I just cannot end up with the logic to achieve this. Is there any handy jquery function that can help me do this? If you can guide me with the logic that would be very helpful.

**UPDATE**

Damn it! I asked for the logic not the solution itself, thanks for the help :)

Comment: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9o4pg7de/) (using `each` and `before`)?

Comment: @user2786485 I think so, can post this as an answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate through each `dt` with `each` and insert an anchor before it with `before`.

also, if you want each anchor `href` to appear only once you can make an object that keeps track of them

```js
var links = {};
$("dt").each(function () {
    var href = "#"+this.innerText[0];
    if (!links[href]) {
     links[href] = true;
  $(this).before('<a href="'+href+'">'+href+'</a>');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt style="font-weight:bold">A1</dt>
<dd>Some description for A1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">A2</dt>
<dd>Some description for A2</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">B1</dt>
<dd>Some description for B1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">C1</dt>
<dd>Some description for C1</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">C2</dt>
<dd>Some description for C2</dd>

<dt style="font-weight:bold">D1</dt>
<dd>Some description for D1</dd>
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9o4pg7de/1/)

```
 $("dt").each(function () {
   var id =$(this).text()[0];
   if(!$("#"+id).length){
    $(this).before('<a href="#'+id+'" id="'+id+'">'+id+'</a>');
   }
 });
```

Comment: I like your code but the other friend answered earlier so I chose that one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Non jQuery

```
 var dts = $('dt');
    for(var i = 0; i<dts.length; i++)
     {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(dts[i].innerHTML);
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.href = dts[i].innerHTML[0];
            $('body')[0].insertBefore(a,dts[i]);
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Totally missed the groups, hence the down voting. =[ My mistake. Glanced too quickly. Updated to fix even though answer is already accepted.

```
var $dts = $('dt');
var used = [];
// Iterate over each one
$.each($dts,
    function (index, obj) {
        // From each get the first letter on text string
        var text = $(obj).text().substring(0, 1);
        if (used.indexOf(text) == -1) {
            used.push(text)
            // Create an anchor with that text as href
            var newLink = $('<a href="#' + text + '">newlink</a>');
            // Insert the anchor before the element
            $(obj).before(newLink);
        }
    }
)
```

Here is a fiddle with it working.
http://jsfiddle.net/gyas74d9/2/

Comment: won't produce expected results

Comment: this will add anchor before each dt?

Comment: Yes it will, why won't it create expected results?

Comment: In his example there is no anchor tag. He wants to insert anchor tags. Not sure why I am being down voted. I gave a working example that produces exactly what he wanted.

Comment: @charlietfl why will this not produce expected results?

Comment: @charlietfl Ah ok, You are right. I apologize. I totally missed the groups.